# How to use MongoSpark connector to create index 2dshere?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am working on a spark code , where I create geospatial object type from using MongoSpark connector https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/java/write-to-mongodb/

```
JavaRDD<Document> document =   ds
              .toJavaRDD()
              .map(f -> {
                 Document doc = new Document();


                      /***************/
                      List<Double> practice_Cordinates = new ArrayList<Double>();
                      practice_Cordinates.add(0.0); // Long
                      practice_Cordinates.add(0.0); // Lat



                      BasicDBObject  GeoSpatial_Obj = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point").
                              append("coordinates", practice_Cordinates);

                      /***************/



                       doc.put("GeoSpatial",  GeoSpatial_Obj); 

                      return doc;

              });

      MongoSpark.save(document);
```

```
 "GeoSpatial" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -73.881631, 
            40.880462
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
```

Now after millions of records pushed, do I need to use typical mongo-java code to get collection and update the index by giving the following code in java

**Spark Code - after MongoSpark.save(DS)**

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DBCollection test = mongoClient.getDB("testdb").getCollection("test");
test.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("GeoSpatial","2dsphere"));
```

Do **MongoSpark** driver have inbuilt method to handle this createindex,ensureindex ?